# Filling missing data with different methods

Tags: python, pandas

I have a couple of a set of data with timestamp, value and quality flag. The value and quality flag are missing for some of the timestamps, and needs to be filled with a dependence on the surrounding data. I.e.,

- If the quality flags on the valid data bracketing the NaN data are different, then set the value and quality flag to the same as the bracketing row with the highest quality flag. In the example below, the first set of NaNs would be replaced with qf=3 and value=3.
- If the quality flags are the same, then interpolate the value between the two valid values on either side. In the example, the second set of NaNs would be replaced by qf = 1 and v = 6 and 9.

Code:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.strptime("2004-01-01 00:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
end = datetime.strptime("2004-01-01 03:00","%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
df = pd.DataFrame(\
    data = {'v' : [1,2,'NaN','NaN','NaN',3,2,1,5,3,'NaN','NaN',12,43,23,12,32,12,12],\
            'qf': [1,1,'NaN','NaN','NaN',3,1,5,1,1,'NaN','NaN',1,3,4,2,1,1,1]},\
    index = pd.date_range(start, end,freq="10min"))
```

I have tried to solve this by finding the NA rows and looping through them, to fix the first criteron, then using interpolate to solve the second. However, this is really slow as I am working with a large set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would just be to do all the possible fills and then choose among them as appropriate.  After doing `df = df.astype(float)` if necessary (your example uses the string `"NaN"`), something like this should work:

```
is_null = df.qf.isnull()
fill_down = df.ffill()
fill_up = df.bfill()

df.loc[is_null & (fill_down.qf > fill_up.qf)] = fill_down
df.loc[is_null & (fill_down.qf < fill_up.qf)] = fill_up
df = df.interpolate()
```

It does more work than is necessary, but it's easy to see what it's doing, and the work that it does do is vectorized and so happens pretty quickly.  On a version of your dataset expanded to be ~10M rows (with the same density of nulls), it takes ~6s on my old notebook.  Depending on your requirements that might suffice.